# Что почитать или где посмотреть лучшие практики по проектированию и структурированию программ на python?

Tags: python

Прочитал первую книгу Лутца, читаю вторую, просматривал Саммерфилда, и еще пару книг по машинному обучению. Но так нигде и не увидел как структурировать программы, как разделять сущности, как правильно разделять модули, как составлять правильно и понятно проект(папки, названия и т.д.). Ни

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это хороший вопрос, но на него сложно дать простой ответ. В любом ремесле очень важна насмотренность, в дизайне и вопросах стиля очень помогают сайты типа Pinterest на которых можно долго рассматривать коллекции людей с развитым вкусом. Для программистом источником вдохновения является Github.com.

В программировании стандарты и понятие красивого дизайна могут сильно зависеть от конкретного фреймворка или сообщества вокруг него. Кроме того коммерческий софт часто имеет главный критерий качества — это приносит ли он деньги или нет.

Я бы разделил ваш вопрос на несколько частей:

- Для того чтобы разобраться как работает большой проект хорошо было бы поучаствовать в каком-то сообществе. Лично мне помогло в свое время в течении многих месяцев переписать часть open source системы публикаций с которой я работал. Потому, что благодаря этому процессу я досконально изучил его внутренности, что сильно повлияло на мой вкус как программиста. Возможно, сейчас можно было бы придумать себе проект типа "сделать новую админку для Django/Flask".
- Хорошее структуирование кода когда начинается новый проект тоже очень важно. То как расположить файлы с кодом, как сделать миграцию, как подключить статику (если это веб-проект) может повлиять на то насколько будет удобно работать с проектом. На [гитхабе в репозитории проекта cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter#categories-of-cookiecutters) есть шаблоны для множества фреймворков. Изучая их вы сможете понять какие проблемы часто появляются перед людьми которые стартуют очередной проект с выбранным фреймворком.
- Хорошо структурированные модули и файлы это скорее вопрос опыта и общей насмотренности. Если вы работаете в дружественном и поддерживающим вас коллективе, то сможете получить советы от коллег. После того как проект или часть уже написаны делать рефакторинг — это нормальная практика.

В целом чувство стиля придет со временем, по мере чтения чужих исходников.

Comment: В целом верно, если не считать, что большая часть github - проекты очень низкого качества и советовать смотреть код там для новичка довольно опрометчиво